# Problems merging Hibernate objects

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, soap

I'm new on publishing something on Stackoverflow but I use it for along time and it was amazing helping me coding.

My problem was the follow:
I receive a object filled in a WebService by SOAP like:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "DogUpdate")
    public @WebResult(name = "resultId")
    Long dogUpdate(
    @WebParam(name = "DogDto", header = true, mode = Mode.IN) DogDto dog);
```

So now I need to update on DB using Hibernate 5.0.2.

The class DogDto is like this:

```
Entity
@Table(name="Dog", indexes={}, uniqueConstraints={})
class Dog implements Dog_i
{

  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DOG_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="DOG_SEQ", sequenceName="DOG_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="Name", length=30)
  private String name;

  @Column(name="BirthDate")
  private Date birthDate;

  @Column(name="NumberDogSons")
  private Long numberDogSons;

@Column(name="namesDogSons")
  private List<String> namesDogSons;
}
```

So my problem is I doesnt know what is the values of the DogDto I receive in my WebService, so I doesnt know what I need to change.

I saw that's Reflection can helps but I have a complex object like (List inside the object dogs and like 'Owner' and others more)

What I can do update the object with info not lost? Because if a field cames null (when is a Long, Integer, int...) it shows like 0 and other relevant problems.

Do you have any suggestion?

Many thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

> So my problem is I doesnt know what is the values of the DogDto I receive in my WebService, so I doesnt know what I need to change.

From you code above, you seem to get a "DogDto dog".

You just have to make hibernate persist this dog object using saveOrUpdate method.

If your ID is well defined Hibernate will update the existing if it exists, otherwise it will insert a new one.

Comment: thanks by the help! But the thing here is:
Imagine that I have a object like {ID: 1, Name:'Jack', birthDate:'22/12/2015', namesDogSons:'Peyroteo', 'Travassos', 'Damas'}

And I receive a Dto like this:
<com:DogDto>
    <com:ID>1</com:ID>
 <com:Name>Sparrow</com:Name>
<com:BirthDate></com:BirthDate>
<com:namesDogSons></com:namesDogSons>
</com:DogDto>

The com:BirthDate and namesDogSons are going to be updated with null... that was my problem....

Comment: If you want to update or not the dog children during update/delete, you can specify it with the CASCADE keyword.